# OSMnx downloaded unexpected edges of a river network, how to fix this?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

I'm using *OSMnx (0.15.1)* to extract a network of rivers. Using the code below I expected to download a river network with only the central way of the river, see **Fig. 1**, which is obtained using *QuickOSM* plugin in *QGIS* with the tag `"waterway=river"`:

[image: QuickOSM]

[Fig. 1 with QuickOSM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95k2f.png)

When using *OSMnx*, the most part of the network within this river catchment seems to be correctly presented as the central way of the river. However, at this particular lat-long point `(51.062981, 13.270961)`, the *OSMnx* tool downloaded the edges of the riverbank as well (**Fig. 2**, grey lines). For some river sections (bottom right), the edges of the riverbank were downloaded instead of the central way of the river. Where is the problem and how can I fix this?

The OSM tag `"waterway"~"river"` was used as a filter. A reproducible example:

```
import osmnx as ox

"""
A simple attempt to download a river network from a point with OSMnx.
"""
# Get a river network and plot it with all edge intersections.
point = 51.062981, 13.270961 # lat, long
G = ox.graph_from_point(point, 
                        dist=1000,
                        custom_filter='["waterway"~"river"]')
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, node_color='r')
```

[image: OSMnx]

[Fig. 2 with OSMnx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bnyrf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter `'["waterway"~"river"]'` matches both "river" and "riverbank", hence you're getting river banks in your graph. Instead, use `=` to just match "river":

```py
G = ox.graph_from_point(point, dist=1000, custom_filter='["waterway"="river"]')
```